# Angular 11: How to user service in regular ts file？

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an utils.ts file which has some exported functions just like deepCopy and sortArray or something, but I want to use a service in some functions, how can I do that?

```
// utils.ts
export function copy(str:string){
  // set clipBoard...
  
  // here I want to use a service, how to use toastService?
  // toastService.success('copied!');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the usual way https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: try to import into your respective modules, from there just add a parameter to the constructor of the component @Vectoria

Comment: @TheViralGriffin I dont't want to create a utilsService, I just want to import utils.ts and do copy function, and this copy function just happened that need toastService.

Comment: @RavitejaV In the component, I just want to copy something by import {copy} from 'utils',and use it just like copy('something'). I don't want to inject some service just like utilService or toastService.

Comment: I don't know if this is a odd needs, but I have a simple utils file, just for simple needs, I don't want to inject service and use it like : this.utilsService.copy('something'), I want to use it like: copy('something')

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is only one way for you: convert your util function into the method of the service and use it everywhere like a normal service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelperService {
  constructor(
    private toastService: ToastService,
  ){}

  public copy(str:string): void{
     // set clipBoard...

     // here I want to use a service, how to use toastService?
     this.toastService.success('copied!');
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
this.helperService.copy('Something');
```

it should be like that, because you need to get ToastService from DI and decorator Injectable will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have lots of service, but this utils.ts I just don't want to convert it to a service, I want to use it like this:    copy('something')...I don't know if it's odd but I do need this.

Answer (score 0):

While you could create a new instance of `ToastService` in your function, I wouldn't recommend that approach as you would lose all the benefits of DI.

It could look as following:

```
export function copy(str:string){
  // set clipBoard...
  
  const toastService = new ToastService();
  toastService.success('copied!');
}
```

Instead, I would recommend to either make your `utils` a service, just like others said (and IMO that's the best solution), or extract common code to another function (if it's possible) and use it in both places. It could look like that:

shared.utils.ts:

```
export function toastSuccess(message: string) {
  // your logic
}
```

toast.service.ts

```
import {toastSuccess} from './shared.utils';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ToastService {
  success(message: string) {
    toastSuccess(message);
  }
}
```

utils.ts

```
import {toastSuccess} from './shared.utils';

export function copy(str:string){
  // set clipBoard...

  toastSuccess('copied!');
}
```